# Failed To Update Table Row in SQLITE Using JOOQ

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, jooq

jooq is generating invalid update statement for sqlite database.

Here is the database table.

```
CREATE TABLE "job" (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  `addressId` text,
   `log` text
)
```

**Valid Statement:**

```
update "job" set "log" = (coalesce("log", ?) || ? || ?) WHERE id > 0
```

**Jooq Generated Statement**

```
update "job" set "job"."log" = (coalesce("job"."log", ?) || ? || ?) where "job"."id" >= ?
```

Here is the Sample Code i ame Using:

```
DSL.using(configuration).update(JOB).set(JOB.LOG, DSL.coalesce(JOB.LOG, "")
                .concat("char(10)", "Hello"))
                .where(JOB.ID.ge(0)).execute()
```

How do i force jooq to generate valid sqlite update statement?

Comment: Did you correctly set up your `configuration` with `SQLDialect.SQLITE`? Also, why do you alias the `JOB` table?

Comment: yes i have configured the same DIALECT. Able to successfully Query the db but update is failing.  i have forgot to remove the alias, updated now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. With a properly configured configuration, there is no column qualification in update statements for SQLite, nor are columns quoted. Can you please show how you create the `configuration`?

Comment: Thanks Lukas Eder for your time,  Unfortunately it's  an IDE issue for some reason the file has not been refreshed where i have added SQLDialect.SQLITE. After printing the DIALECT to console i came to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this is that you did not correctly configure your `configuration` with the `SQLDialect.SQLITE` dialect. In that dialect, the column references in the `set` clause would not be qualified, neither would any column or table be quoted.

Comment: i have rechecked yesterday after your comment but didn't clearly debug the issue.